# Sitemap set noindex attribute

Tags: sitemap

I need to set `noindex` attribute for each generated `sitemap XML`. I create `sitemap.xml` using Sitemap Controller

```
  [Route("sitemap_index.xml")]
        public ActionResult SitemapIndexXml()
        {
            return this.TryInvoke<ActionResult>(() =>
            {
                var siteName = SitecoreConstants.DefaultSiteName;
                var uri = Request.Url;
                if (uri != null)
                {
                    var currentSite = SiteFacade.GetSiteNameByHostName(uri.Host);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentSite))
                    {
                        siteName = currentSite;
                    }
                }

                var expirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                var xml = this.MemoryCacheService.GetOrSet(
                    string.Format(SitemapCacheKey, siteName, string.Empty, "sitemap_index"),
                    expirationDate,
                    () => this.SitemapSerializationService.SerializeSitemapIndex(siteName));

                return this.Content(xml, "xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            }, "SitemapController.SitemapIndexXml");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in several ways, I will describe 2 ways below:

1. **Robots.txt**: If you want to exclude all the pages below a particular route, you can add an entry in the Robots.txt like below:

> Disallow: /Account/*

1. **A Sitemap settings template**: To have a more granular control at the page level, you should create a base template and include a setting for enable/disable in the crawling index. This template should be referenced in all the page items. In the header component, you can then include a check to add meta tag `<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">` based on the setting opted for the page.

Comment: What about   HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "noindex");

For 1) didn't Google Webmaster tool disabled options via Robots.txt in 2019.

Comment: yes you may use that as well, as I said there are several ways to achieve what you want.